# Create Nginx redirect for a url with spaces (%20)

Tags: nginx, redirect

I need to create redirects for URLs where the html file name had spaces in it.

I need the nginx equivalent to this:

```
Redirect 301 "/Poorly Titled File.html" http://domain.com/new-url/
```

I have tried:

```
rewrite ^/Old\%20Page\%20Title.html$ $scheme://domain.com/new-url/ permanent;


location /Old\%20Page\%20Title.html{
return 301 $scheme://domain.com/new-url/;
}
```

with and without escaping the %'s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `'` around the location:

```
location '/Old Page Title.html' {
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com/new-url/;
}
```

Also see SO question [Nginx rewrite that includes a blank spce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101690/nginx-rewrite-that-includes-a-blank-spce).